# changing he background image of the application

Tags: android

Hi I am beginner in android and I am trying to learn it, I wrote a small code for changing the  `background`  image of the application when clicking on some button:

```
public void processClicks(View display)
{
    display.setBackgroundResource(@drawable/fgd4);
}
```

but it got me an error message that : 
**drawable cannot be resolved to a variable
fgd4 cannot be resolved to a variable**

but I have created a folder named  `drawable`  in the  `res`  folder and I put the  `fgd4.jpg`  image in it.

Please help me to solve this small problem

Answer (score 1):

You must reference your drawable in code differently than you do in your XML layouts.

`display.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.fgd4 );`

Comment: Hi thank you. the error was corrected, but when I run the application and click on the button, it doesn't work and forces the application to close

Answer (score 0):

**Try Like This:**

display.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fgd4);